# Convert negative text to decimal number in Power Query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, excel-2016

How to convert negative numbers stored as text into decimal using Power Query?

I am having text data generated from a software in this format:

```
11334;-          6,200;10;"040";"MAT";11;"CLEANSORB CS3G";"Abgang in Produktion";"2-GR";ja;446,600;"MatSchein Abg in Fertig";"MAT";"";07.10.2020 08:13:49;"";"PPA";3646;10,0;02;17.529,820;07.10.2020;230;2.246,600;"99";17.529,820
11334;-          2,200;10;"040";"MAT";11;"CLEANSORB CS3G";"Abgang in Produktion";"2-GR";ja;446,600;"MatSchein Abg in Fertig";"MAT";"";07.10.2020 08:13:49;"";"PPA";3646;10,0;02;17.529,820;07.10.2020;230;2.246,600;"99";17.529,820
11334;-          126,200;10;"040";"MAT";11;"CLEANSORB CS3G";"Abgang in Produktion";"2-GR";ja;446,600;"MatSchein Abg in Fertig";"MAT";"";07.10.2020 08:13:49;"";"PPA";3646;10,0;02;17.529,820;07.10.2020;230;2.246,600;"99";17.529,820
11334;-          15,000;10;"040";"MAT";11;"CLEANSORB CS3G";"Abgang in Produktion";"2-GR";ja;446,600;"MatSchein Abg in Fertig";"MAT";"";07.10.2020 08:13:49;"";"PPA";3646;10,0;02;17.529,820;07.10.2020;230;2.246,600;"99";17.529,820
11334;          10,200;10;"040";"MAT";11;"CLEANSORB CS3G";"Abgang in Produktion";"2-GR";ja;446,600;"MatSchein Abg in Fertig";"MAT";"";07.10.2020 08:13:49;"";"PPA";3646;10,0;02;17.529,820;07.10.2020;230;2.246,600;"99";17.529,820
```

And when I try to use this with Power Query to convert to decimal number I am getting an error:

[image]

[image]

As you can notice there are all of a sudden lot of empty spaces after the (minus) sign, and if I try to do >replace< option it is working partly because of different number of spaces...
I tried to change locals, format, file origin, all those options that I am capable of but nothing...

Can someone help why and what is causing this issue?

p.s After downloading this file using software that is generating this text/csv files, it firstly (automatically) opens file in read mode (where looks all fine) but I need to save it in .xlsx for instance and the use power query...so you can imagine that is always manual work...and it is strange why PowerQ cant read this file > also I tried in Power BI but same thing...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for data but plain, readable, copyable text, so everyone at home can follow along.

Comment: It's not clear why replacing wouldn't just work. The variable number of spaces is irrelevant -- if you simply tell Power Query to replace a single space with nothing, it will replace *all* spaces with nothing. As for why opening the CSV directly might not work directly, there's not enough of it displayed here to tell. If you can replicate the problem even with a CSV consisting of a single line, we could too.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sorry, I will edit right now.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hey, it is functioning actually! My bad....replace was actually fine!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(Source, {"ColumnWithSpaces", each Number.From(Text.Remove(_,{" "})), type number})
```